# how to get property by getting the binding expression

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I Have a xaml that conatins this binding expression

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsMain}
```

And I want to get the field IsMain in the code behind...

How do i do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Take from the place where you bind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have TextBlock like this in XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="{Binding Path=IsMain}"/>
```

you can get property name in code behind like this:

```
var bindingExpression = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(textBlock, 
                            TextBlock.TextProperty);
string propertyName = bindingExpression.ParentBinding.Path.Path;
```

*Note* : In your case replace ***textBlock*** with your control instance name and ***TextBlock.TextProperty*** with Dependency property with target DP on which binding is applied.